# PowerBI Desktop with Impala - how select the schema?

Tags: odbc, powerbi, impala, powerbi-desktop

Good morning,

I'm facing a strange behavior and trying to provide some support to our customer.

We need to create a power bi report connecting to an Impala database. An ODBC connection will be used in this case (Note that the Impala connection has the same problem as describe below).

I do a "Get Data", select our DSN and enter the user-id and password. The problem is that the only db I see is the "**default**" database and I can't see the XYZ database. I tried to add **schema=XYZ** but nothing change.

I also modified the default database defined in the ODBC driver by replacing `default` with `XYZ`, no change.

Any ideas?

Comment: The ODBC DSN you created - can you pls try creating system DSN ? And i hope you are using an user which has access to all the databases(schemas).

Comment: Sounds like authorization issue with your `user-id`... Could you enable ODBC driver logging to see if there are any errors?

Comment: Little status of the day- After investigations I noticed that whatever account I enter to initiate the ODBC connection, it uses my own credentials to access the data. I will try to activate the logging on the ODBC driver to see what's happen.

Comment: @KoushikRoy, yes we have set a system dsn and the tech ID I'm using has access to our database (I've double cross-check with dbeaver).

Comment: @mazaneicha, I've activate the logs but nothing relevant **except** I've got a message saying it's my user account instead the tech account which is used (ps: my account does not have access to this database). It's really weird ;

Comment: That would certainly explain why your BI tool can't "see" XYZ database. Is BI tool configured to pass through the login credentials? What authentication mechanism is DSN set up to use?

Comment: Mechanism : Kerberos  
Host FQDN : _HOST  
Service Name : Impala 
Canonicalize Principal FQDN flagged ON  
SSL is activated